# Unable to install devstack

Tags: openstack

```
$ sudo apt-get install git 
[sudo] password for shrihari:  
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... 
Done git is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Further I am trying to install devstack, but some network error after executing the following:

```
$ git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
Cloning into 'devstack'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack/': Failed to connect to git.openstack.org port 443: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: you already have git installed. What are you trying to do ? Get git before devstack? What's your ubuntu version?

Comment: I too followed the link provided by you.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS is my ubuntu desktop version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same issue, but the following worked for me

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
```

or

```
git clone git://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [link](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/)

and was able to install it without any issues. I am having Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS

Answer (score -1):

je trouve une erreur de la sorte quand je veux cloner devstack :
-- fatal: unable to access 'https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack/': GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received
j'ai remédie à cette erreur en exécutent simultanément les commandes ci-après:

1. sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
2. git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git